# Why behavior changes as order of a emplace_back / push_back changes ? Why number of Constructor increases?

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, push-back

```
class Buffer
{
    unsigned char* ptr{nullptr};
    size_t length{0};
public:
    Buffer() :
    ptr(nullptr),
    length(0)
    {std::cout<<"\n In Buffer()\n";}


    explicit Buffer(size_t const size):
    ptr(new unsigned char[size] {0}),
    length (size)
    {std::cout<<"\n In explicit Buffer(size_t const size)\n";}

    ~Buffer()
    {
        if (nullptr != ptr)     delete [] ptr;
    }


//     Causing runtime nullptr exception
//     Buffer(Buffer const& obj) :
//     ptr(new unsigned char[obj.length] {0}),
//     length (obj.getLength())
//     {   std::cout<<"\n In Buffer(Buffer const& obj)\n";}

    // Unnessary Fixed Copy Constructor
    Buffer(Buffer const& obj) noexcept
    {
        std::cout<<"\n In Buffer(Buffer const& obj)\n";
        std::cout<<"\n obj Details : Length = "<<obj.getLength()<<std::boolalpha<<": (ptr == nullptr) = "<<(nullptr == obj.getPtr())<<"\n";
        if (obj.length == 0)
            ptr = nullptr;
        else
            ptr = new unsigned char[obj.length] {0};
        length = obj.length;
    }

    Buffer& operator=(Buffer const obj)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n In Buffer& operator=(Buffer const obj)\n";
        if (this == &obj)   return *this;
        delete [] this->ptr;
        this->ptr = new unsigned char[obj.length]{0};
        this->length = obj.length;
        return *this;
    }

    Buffer(Buffer && data)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n In Buffer(Buffer && data)\n";
        std::cout<<"\n obj Details : Length = "<<data.getLength()<<std::boolalpha<<": (ptr == nullptr) = "<<(nullptr == data.getPtr())<<"\n";
        ptr = data.ptr;
        length = data.length;
        data.ptr = nullptr;
        data.length = 0;
    }

    Buffer& operator=(Buffer&& data)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n In Buffer& operator=(Buffer&& data)\n";
        if (this == &data)  return *this;
        this->ptr = data.ptr;
        this->length = data.length;
        data.ptr = nullptr;
        data.length = 0;
        return *this;
    }

    size_t getLength() const {return length;}
    unsigned char* getPtr() const {return ptr;}
};
```

---------Driver CODE---------

```
std::vector<Buffer> v;
std::cout<<"\nemplace_back()\n";
v.emplace_back();
std::cout<<"\npush_back(Buffer(2))\n";
v.push_back(Buffer(2));
```

---------Output With By Book Copy Constructor---------

emplace_back()

In Buffer()

push_back(Buffer(2))

In explicit Buffer(size_t const size)

In Buffer(Buffer && data)

obj Details : Length = 2: (ptr == nullptr) = false
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc

---------Output With Unnessary Fix in Copy Constructor---------

emplace_back()

In Buffer()

push_back(Buffer(2))

In explicit Buffer(size_t const size)

In Buffer(Buffer && data)

obj Details : Length = 2: (ptr == nullptr) = false

In Buffer(Buffer const& obj)

obj Details : Length = 0: (ptr == nullptr) = true
Program ended with exit code: 0

---------Driver CODE---------

```
std::vector<Buffer> v;
std::cout<<"\npush_back(Buffer(2))\n";
v.push_back(Buffer(2));
std::cout<<"\nemplace_back()\n";
v.emplace_back();
```

---------Output With By Book Copy Constructor---------

push_back(Buffer(2))

In explicit Buffer(size_t const size)

In Buffer(Buffer && data)

obj Details : Length = 2: (ptr == nullptr) = false

emplace_back()

In Buffer()

In Buffer(Buffer const& obj)
Program ended with exit code: 0

---------Output With Unnessary Fix in Copy Constructor---------

push_back(Buffer(2))

In explicit Buffer(size_t const size)

In Buffer(Buffer && data)

obj Details : Length = 2: (ptr == nullptr) = false

emplace_back()

In Buffer()

In Buffer(Buffer const& obj)

obj Details : Length = 2: (ptr == nullptr) = false

### Program ended with exit code: 0

Answer (score 0):

`new unsigned char[obj.length] {0}` exhibits undefined behavior when `obj.length == 0`.

> **[expr.new]/7** The *expression* in a *noptr-new-declarator* is erroneous if:
>   (7.4) — the *new-initializer* is a *braced-init-list* and the number of array elements for which initializers are provided ... exceeds the number of elements to initialize.

"*Expression*" here refers to the array size inside square brackets.

The copy constructor, which triggers this undefined behavior, is called by `vector` when it needs to reallocate its storage from 1 to 2 elements. That's why the problem manifests when you push zero-sized buffer first, then non-zero-sized (whereupon the zero-sized one is copied), but not the other way round.

---

You may want to mark your move constructor `noexcept`, then the vector would use it when reallocating, in place of the copy constructor.